# Can't select or edit Textfield inside Tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a controller `EditProfileController: UITableViewController` and a cell `EditProfileCell: UITableViewCell`

```
extension EditProfileController {
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! EditProfileCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

My `EditProfileCell`

This is my TextField:

```
class EditProfileCell: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var infoTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.borderStyle = .none
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        tf.textAlignment = .left
        tf.textColor = .white
        tf.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return tf
    }()

}
```

The Problem: I can edit the infos for the textfields using the simulator. But when I'm running the app on my iPhone, I'm not able to even select the Textfield, not even the keyboard shows up.

I've tested adding `cell.infoTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` on the extension, and it works, but this makes only the last textfield become editable.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there something that might be covering the text field?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet where you are attaching this lazily created text field in cell's content view? Also please attach the full implementation of your `EditProfileCell`.

Comment: I just realized that I was. adding the `becomeFirstResponder()` to the `numberOfRowsInSection` instead of the `didSelectRowAt`. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled` to false

```
extension EditProfileController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! EditProfileCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        return cell
     }
}
```